# Adaptive Issuance Adoption phase and issuance rate is computation

Tags: adaptive-issuance

[This blog](https://tezos.gitlab.io/alpha/adaptive_issuance.html) states that after activation of adaptive issuance, there will be an adoption phase of 7 cycles. It also states that the issuance rate is computed 5 cycles in advance. Will the issuance rate be computed during the adoption phase so that the effect on issuance should be seen after 7 cycles? Or is it the case that 12 total cycles will pass before the issuance rate is effected by adaptive issuance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** Indeed, after the voting threshold is met, we would keep the existing issuance and rewardsformula for 12 cycles.

Note that when we say "activation of the guarded features", we consider the 7 cycles period to happen before the activation -- which would take place at the beginning of the next cycle (the 8th in OP's count). During the Adoption phase, the current issuance/reward formulas would be used.

Then, Adaptive Issuance would activate and start computing the issuance rate and rewards at the end of each subsequent cycles for the  5th upcoming cycle  -- at the end of the 8th cycle for cycle 13th, etc.

Until then (in the 8th to 12th cycles in the  OP's count), issuance rate/reward values would follow the current mechanism.

**NB:**  The length of these periods are defined by parametric  protocol constants `PRESERVED_CYCLES` and `MAX_SLASHING_PERIOD`. In the [docs](https://tezos.gitlab.io/alpha/adaptive_issuance.html), we currently use the values for Mainnet (5 and, respectively,  2). But these might differ in other test networks: Oxfordnet and Ghostnet, for instance.